# Why adding try except block in if statement and the program says variable not defined

Tags: python, error-handling

I want to write a program that is about tools and has three choices--calculator, random number selector, and calendar. However, when I am trying to use try-except for invalid user input, the variable in the if statement is said as undefined. The codes are the following:

```
        if user_input == 0:
        try:
            small_option = int(
            input("Which operation do you want to do? \n 1. Adding \n 2. Subtracting \n 3. Multiplying "
                  "\n 4. Dividing"))
            small_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
            user_option = small_list[small_option]
        except IndexError:
            print("Invalid option")
```

Then the next variable in the if statement is undefined, the following lines:

```
                if user_option == 0:
                num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
                num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
```

When I ran it, the program says `Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/31459/PycharmProjects/Useful programs/Tools.py", line 41, in <module> if user_option == 0: NameError: name 'user_option' is not defined`

```
import calendar
import random




def adding(para1, para2):
    return para1 + para2



def substract(para1, para2):
    return para1 - para2



def multiplying(para1, para2):
    return para1 * para2



def dividing(para1, para2):
    return para1 / para2


while True:
    try:
        big_option = input("Which tool will you use? \n 0. Calculator \n 1. Calender \n 2. Random number generator")
        big_list = [0, 1, 2]
        big_option_int = int(big_option)
        user_input = big_list[big_option_int]
        if user_input == 0:
            try:
                small_option = int(
                input("Which operation do you want to do? \n 1. Adding \n 2. Subtracting \n 3. Multiplying "
                      "\n 4. Dividing"))
                small_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
                user_option = small_list[small_option]
            except IndexError:
                print("Invalid option")
                if user_option == 0:
                    num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
                    num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
                if user_option == 1:
                    print("The sum is", num1, "+", num2, adding(num1, num2))
                elif user_option == 2:
                    print("The subtraction is", num1, "-", num2, substract(num1, num2))
                elif user_option == 3:
                    print("The multiplying is", num1, "*", num2, multiplying(num1, num2))
                else:
                    print("The divide is", num1, "/", num2, dividing(num1, num2))
                    break
            if user_option == 1:
                user_year_str = input("Please input the year you want to get.")
                user_month_str = input("Please input the month you want to get.")
                user_year = int(user_year_str)
                user_month = int(user_month_str)
                calendar.month(user_year, user_month)
            else:
                random_input_1 = input("Please input the 1st number:")
                random_input_2 = input("Please input the 2nd number:")
                random_input_1_int = int(random_input_1)
                random_input_2_int = int(random_input_2)
                random.randint(random_input_1_int, random_input_2_int)
    except IndexError:
        print("Invalid option")
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and format the code as it appears in your editor. Indentation is extremely important in Python, the current code would give an IndentationError, and it's tough to guess what your code actually looks like. So help us help you by posting minimal, complete code that reproduces your question.

Answer (score 0):

the user_option needs to be defined

are you sure you defined the variable before using the conditional statement?

it needs to have a value before using the conditional statement

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the try block raises an error and it fails to initialize variable`user_option`. Hence, it raises an error.

Try adding this as an alternative

```
user_option = small_option -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Every object(here: variable) in python has a scope, and in that scope is recognizable. out of its scope it's unrecognizable.

The scope of user_option variable is the try block that in it user_option is defined.
if you want to use user_option out of try block you should defined it in bigger scope (means out of try block that it's defined).

Answer (score 0):

You're making option 4 invalid by accessing the list by direct index.

Indices start at 0, so consequently option 4 does not exist, that is an Index Error.
1-3 does not raise an error as the user_option is defined without exception. But your "0" option in `small_list` will never be used.

Simply initializing the variable `user_option` before the try/catch will fix the `UnboundLocalError`. But not the flaw in your logic. You could subract the given option value by one to turn it into a 0-starting index as you have defined the `small_list` variable

`small_list[small_option-1]` will retrieve 0 when you write 1 and 3 when you write 4, all of which are defined indices of `small_list`.

```
user_option = None        # by defining the variable first, we avoid the UnboundLocalError
try:
    small_option = int(
    input("Which operation do you want to do? \n 1. Adding \n 2. Subtracting \n 3. Multiplying "
            "\n 4. Dividing"))
    small_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    user_option = small_list[small_option-1]        # 1. Adding = small_list[0], 2. Subtracting = small_list[1], etc..
except IndexError:
    print("Invalid option")
if user_option == 0:
    num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
```